# Dynamically change inner element text to a href link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am creating a web extension and need to dynamically change inner text to a link. Since it's a web extension, I can't make too many assumptions about where this text will be located. Furthermore, the changes need to be dynamically loaded (this is the main problem I have).

For example, I need to find all instances of the text "foo" on a page and replace it with `<a href="www.mylink.com">foo</a>`, so that the text on the page now is displayed as a link. I have the following functions, which correctly replaces occurrences, but the `<a>` tag that it inserts simply gets displayed in the browser as the raw html, instead of being displayed as a link.

```js
function replace_with_link()
{
  var link = "https://google.com";
  var name = "Lorem Ipsum";
 var link_wrapper = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + name + "</a>";
 replaceText('*', name, link_wrapper, 'g');
}

function replaceText(selector, text, newText, flags) 
{
 var matcher = new RegExp(text, flags);
 $(selector).each(function () 
 {
  var $this = $(this);
  var replaced_text = "";
  if (!$this.children().length)
  {
     $this.text($this.text().replace(matcher, newText));
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<button onclick="replace_with_link();">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `$this.text(...)` to `$this.html(...)`.

Comment: Please don't post links to your code. Links can die over time. Just include your code, right here, in a "code snippet".

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus, I included both the link and the source. Figured it was the best of both worlds.

Comment: We don't really want the external link at all. We want to be able to have everything right here. And, since a code snippet allows us to run the code, there is no need for the Fiddle.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks Scott!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: Change [`$this.text(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to [`$this.html(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

The longer answer is the main difference between the two methods:

- The `html` method will "set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements".
- The `text` method will also set the content of the elements but "escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML."

That last point is critical because "to do so, it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as HTML". This basically means that any HTML would be escaped so as to be a able to be displayed as text.

```
function replace_with_link() {
  var link = "https://google.com";
  var name = "Lorem Ipsum";
  var link_wrapper = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + name + "</a>";
  replaceText('*', name, link_wrapper, 'g');
}

function replaceText(selector, text, newText, flags) {
  var matcher = new RegExp(text, flags);
  $(selector).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var replaced_text = "";
    if (!$this.children().length) {
      $this.html($this.text().replace(matcher, newText));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: A good answer should explain "why" the code should be changed, not just what to change it to.

Comment: Hey Jason, sure enough, this worked! I'll accept this as the answer, but could you also edit your answer to include the "why?" Thanks!

Comment: Guys, slow down. Ahahahahha... I was actively editing the answer. :D If you check my answer history you will see not only is the "why" included but links to the corresponding documentation to show how to find the answers.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jason :D

Comment: It didn't take long to see that you didn't really post a good answer. Now, that you've made it better, I've retracted my down vote. There's no way for us to know that you are working on making your answer better. It should be "good" from the start.

Comment: @AaronDevelops  Unfortunately it's tough to give a long form answer on SO because in the time it takes you to write out a well thought and formatted response a bunch of other people have just tossed up 1 liners and then your answer gets pushed to the bottom. So, to keep your "place in line", the only option is to post and actively edit. 

Comment: I don't think that's the case at all. It's not a race. Post a good answer and then make it even better. I usually post enough to explain the issue and the solution and then go back and add the links to the documentation after.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Working on my personal experience over quite a few years, this is exactly what I see the every once in a while I log on to attempt to help (I actually abandoned a previous account because I hadn't logged in forever and couldn't remember what email I had used). It's not perfect and I hate that is how it works. SO is littered with questions that have much better researched and thoughtful answers that aren't the accepted one because they were posted a few minutes after the other ones were.

Answer (score 1):

The function **[`$.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** returns as text the already rendered/processed HTML by the engine and receives the text to be shown.

In your approach, you're passing as text the new generated HTML, so the engine will handle it as text and none rendering process will be executed.

To render that new generated HTML use the function **[`$.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** instead.

```js
function replace_with_link() {
  var link = "https://google.com";
  var name = "Lorem Ipsum";
  var link_wrapper = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + name + "</a>";
  replaceText('*', name, link_wrapper, 'g');
}

function replaceText(selector, text, newText, flags) {
  var matcher = new RegExp(text, flags);
  $(selector).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var replaced_text = "";
    if (!$this.children().length) {
      $this.html($this.text().replace(matcher, newText));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <button onclick="replace_with_link();">Click me</button>

</body>

</html>
```

**Aside note**, for future approaches use the function **[`$.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** to bind events to the elements.

Comment: *The function $.text() returns as text the rendered/processed HTML* That's not the case. That's what `.html()` does. `.text()` does not process the HTML at all. That's the difference between it and `.html()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus probably my explanation was confusing.  Let me fix it!